# cannot get year-month interval

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am learning PL-SQL and the exercise is to find the year-month interval difference between two dates. I wrote the following code:

```
DECLARE
  t1 TIMESTAMP (2) WITH TIME ZONE :=  to_timestamp_tz('2019-01-21 21:05:53.46 +02:00',
                        'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZH:TZM');
  t3 TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE := to_timestamp_tz('2020-01-21 21:05:53.46 +02:00',
                        'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZH:TZM');                       
  ym INTERVAL YEAR(2) to MONTH;   
BEGIN
--  ym := '10-2';
  ym := t3-t1;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ym);
END;
```

I would expect the ym variable to give '01-0' (1 year difference), but I get an error:

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 9, column 9:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
ORA-06550: line 9, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

I am really confused why this is happening, I tried changing the precision of the `YEAR(_)`, but that doesn't help.

If `ym` is of datatype `INTERVAL DAY(2) to SECOND(2)`, I get correct result. If I replace ym to `ym := '10-2';` it also works. But with `ym INTERVAL YEAR(2) to MONTH` it is not working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found in the [psoug.org examples](http://psoug.org/reference/timestamp.html) that you could use this syntax:

```
ym := (t3-t1) year to month;
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8e216ef3693f3c4c8b56d5b07afa9eee)</sup>**

Comment: Can you please explain what adding ```year to month``` does?
How is it different from (omitted extra code because of space)
```DECLARE
  ds INTERVAL DAY(2) to SECOND(2);  
BEGIN
  ds := t3 - t1;  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ds);
END; ```

Comment: @Kay `(t3-t1)` implicitly defaults to generating a `DAY TO SECOND` interval. `(t3 - t1) year to month` explicitly generates a `YEAR TO MONTH` interval and `(t3 - t1) day to second` would explicitly generate a `DAY TO SECOND` interval. The behaviour is quite difficult to find in the Oracle documentation but its in [this example](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-9B4F00D0-821A-4342-95AA-30CA43DBA124).

Comment: I checked returned values using `dump()` and `(t3-t1)` returns 190 (interval day to second)  and `(t3-t1) year to month` returns 189 (interval year to month), so it works like conversion of interval types. I never used this syntax, never needed it, it is new for me too, but it is what you asked for.

Answer (score 2):

`t3-t1` does not work as the resulting value is of the `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` data type and there is no implicit cast to `INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH`.

Instead, you can use `NUMTOYMINTERVAL( MONTHS_BETWEEN( t3, t1 ), 'MONTH' );` to dynamically create the correct data type:

```sql
DECLARE
  t1 TIMESTAMP (2) WITH TIME ZONE :=  to_timestamp_tz('2019-01-21 21:05:53.46 +02:00',
                        'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZH:TZM');
  t3 TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE := to_timestamp_tz('2020-01-21 21:05:53.46 +02:00',
                        'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZH:TZM');                       
  ym INTERVAL YEAR(2) to MONTH;   
BEGIN
  ym := NUMTOYMINTERVAL( MONTHS_BETWEEN( t3, t1 ), 'MONTH' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ym);
END;
/
```

outputs:

> ```
> +01-00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6ceb2948bb276d26aa43e4170f7d8029)*

Comment: What would be the correct value of t3, to make ym := t3-t1 work? Or can you please show me an example where you subtract two timestamps and get the result in the YEAR(2) to MONTH format? I am confused why the result is of INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND and not INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH.

Comment: [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-E405BBC7-DA9A-4DF2-9F22-E60CB9EC0705) just states `TIMESTAMP - TIMESTAMP = INTERVAL` but does not distinct `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` and `INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH`. Seems to be a design decision done by Oracle.

Comment: apparently it defaults to ```DAY TO SECOND```